# Selecting Radio Option based on Query String

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, query-string

I'm having some trouble with selecting the radio option affiliated to the query string. I have the following code in place...

```
<?php if ( $_GET['fp'] == 'floorplanfive' ) { ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#choice_2_4').attr('checked', 'checked');
    console.log("test");
  </script>
<?php } ?>
```

The console is showing the message 'test' but the radio option is not being selected.

The page can be [found here.](http://uptownlofts.ibistrail.com/apply-for-residency/?fp=floorplanfive)

Please help out. :-)

Comment: use `==` comparison operator instead of `=` assignment. assignment will always return true.

Comment: I just updated that now, but it's still not working. Thank you though! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your code inside of the `$(document).ready()` function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // your code
});
```

Comment: Wow!! I can't believe I forgot that, haha. I'll accept your answer in 8 minutes (once it's available).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
jQuery('#choice_2_4').prop('checked', true);
```

***Edit:*** if your radio button is loaded after this code, use it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#choice_2_4').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Comment: @BrianSchroeter, see my `EDIT:` Section

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` comparison operator instead of `=` assignment.

Assignment in if condition will always return true.

Change your code to:

```
<?php if ( $_GET['fp'] == 'floorplanfive' ) { ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#choice_2_4').attr('checked', 'checked');
    console.log("test");
  </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Although your observation is good,This does not makes any differance to the problem

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following:**

```
jQuery('#choice_2_4').attr('checked', true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```